# split file into two parts, at a pattern

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk, split

How to split a large file into two parts, at a pattern?

Given an example `file.txt`:

```
ABC
EFG
XYZ
HIJ
KNL
```

I want to split this file at `XYZ` such that `file1` contains lines up-to `XYZ` and rest of the lines in `file2`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

With `awk` you can do:

```
awk '{print >out}; /XYZ/{out="file2"}' out=file1 largefile
```

**Explanation:** The first `awk` argument (`out=file1`) defines a variable with the filename that will be used for output while the subsequent argument (`largefile`) is processed. The `awk` program will print all lines to the file specified by the variable `out` (`{print >out}`). If the pattern `XYZ` will be found the output variable will be redefined to point to the new file (`{out="file2}"`) which will be used as target to print the subsequent data lines.

**References:**

- gawk manual: Redirection http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Redirection.html#Redirection

Answer (score 19):

This is a job for [`csplit`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/csplit.html):

```
csplit -sf file -n 1 large_file /XYZ/
```

would `s`ilently split the file, creating pieces with pre`f`ix `file` and `n`umbered using a single digit, e.g. `file0` etc. Note that using `/regex/` would split up to, but not including the line that matches `regex`. To split up to *and* including the line matching `regex` add a `+1` offset:

```
csplit -sf file -n 1 large_file /XYZ/+1
```

This creates two files,  `file0` and `file1`. If you absolutely need them to be named `file1` and `file2` you could always add an empty pattern to the `csplit` command and remove the first file:

```sh
csplit -sf file -n 1 large_file // /XYZ/+1
```

creates `file0`, `file1` and `file2` but `file0` is empty so you can safely remove it:

```
rm -f file0
```

Answer (score 6):

```
{ sed '/XYZ/q' >file1; cat >file2; } <infile
```

With GNU `sed` you should use the `-u`nbuffered switch. Most other `sed`s should just work though.

To leave XYZ out...

```
{ sed -n '/XYZ/q;p'; cat >file2; } <infile >file1
```

Answer (score 6):

With a modern `ksh` here's a shell variant (i.e. without `sed`) of one of the `sed` based answers above:

```
{ read in <##XYZ ; print "$in" ; cat >file2 ;} <largefile >file1
```

And another variant in `ksh` alone (i.e. also omitting the `cat`):

```
{ read in <##XYZ ; print "$in" ; { read <##"" ;} >file2 ;} <largefile >file1
```

(The pure `ksh` solution seem to be quite performant; on a 2.4 GB test file it needed 19-21 sec, compared to 39-47 sec with the `sed`/`cat` based approach).

Comment: It's [very](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/175378/how-is-ksh93-so-fast) fast. But I don't think you need to `read` and `print` - you should just let it go to output all its own. The performance gets better if you build the AST toolkit wholly and get all of the `ksh` builtins compiled in - it's weird to me that `sed` isn't one of them, actually. But with stuff like `while <file do` I guess you don't need `sed` so much...

Comment: I am curious though - how did `awk` perform in your benchmark? And while I'm pretty sure `ksh` will likely always win this fight, if you're using a GNU `sed` you're not being very fair to `sed` - GNU's `-u`nbuffered is a piss-poor approach to POSIXLY ensuring the descriptor's offset is left where the program quit it - there should be no need to slow down the regular operation of the program - buffering is fine - all `sed` should have to do is lseek the descriptor when finished. For whatever reason GNU reverses that mentality.

Comment: @mikeserv; The redirection pattern match is done until the pattern is found, and the line with the found pattern will not be printed if not explicitly done as depicted. (At least that showed my test.) Note that there's no `while`; the printing is implicitly done as the defined side effect of the `<##` redirection operator. And only the matching line needs printing. (That way the shell feature implementation is most flexible for support of incl./excl.) An explicit `while` loop I'd expect to be significant slower (but haven't checked).

Comment: I know there's no `while` - that's a different syntax for something else *(Korn calls it **file-scan** mode)*. The current line can always be printed with `head`, it's probably what I would use. Either way - `ksh` is *always* going ro win this.

Comment: @mikeserv; (WRT your second comment): I didn't mean to be fair or unfair; just used your sed code pattern and implemented it natively in ksh. The awk logic is (while similar) but different, so I didn't use it as base for the shell only code. But I measured that as well, and (as expected) it's slower than sed; ~60 sec.

Comment: It's not really you - GNU holds the responsibility in that department. Iupvoted this because it's an awesome answer - and that's true. I was just pointing out that GNU `sed` is a poor candidate for contention - but `ksh` is would be the champion regardless.

Comment: @mikeserv; Ah, okay. BTW, I just tried the `head` instead of the `read`; it seems only a little bit slower, but it's terser code: `{ head -1 <##XYZ ; { read <##"" ;} >file4 ;} <largefile >file3`.

Comment: Is your `head ` builtin?

Comment: @mikeserv; Good point; it wasn't. But when I activate the builtin (just done and checked the results) it's the same numbers, strangely. (Maybe some function call overhead compared to read?)

Answer (score 3):

Try this with GNU sed:

```
sed -n -e '1,/XYZ/w file1' -e '/XYZ/,${/XYZ/d;w file2' -e '}' large_file
```

Comment: Shorter: `sed -e '1,/XYZ/{w file1' -e 'd}' large_file > file2`

Answer (score 1):

An easy hack is to print either to STDOUT or STDERR, depending on whether the target pattern has been matched. You can then use the shell's [redirection operators](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/159513/22222) to redirect the output accordingly. For example, in Perl, assuming the input file is called `f` and the two output files `f1` and `f2`:

1. Discarding the line that matches the split pattern:

   ```
   perl -ne 'if(/XYZ/){$a=1; next} ; $a==1 ? print STDERR : print STDOUT;' f >f1 2>f2
   ```
2. Including the matched line:

   ```
   perl -ne '$a=1 if /XYZ/; $a==1 ? print STDERR : print STDOUT;' f >f1 2>f2
   ```

Alternatively, print to different file handles:

1. Discarding the line that matches the split pattern:

   ```
   perl -ne 'BEGIN{open($fh1,">","f1");open($fh2,">","f2");}
   if(/XYZ/){$a=1; next}$a==1 ? print $fh1 "$_" : print $fh2 "$_";' f
   ```
2. Including the matched line:

   ```
   perl -ne 'BEGIN{open($fh1,">","f1"); open($fh2,">","f2");}
             $a=1 if /XYZ/; $a==1 ? print $fh1 "$_" : print $fh2 "$_";' f
   ```