# Split file in two on line before pattern

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk, split

This is an almost identical question to [split file into two parts, at a pattern](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/202514/split-file-into-two-parts-at-a-pattern) but instead of having the lines up to XYZ in `file1` in the example `file.txt`:

```
ABC
EFG
XYZ
HIJ
KNL
```

I want to have the XYZ included in `file2` (but `XYZ` is still the pattern to divide on). What I have now is using this answer: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/202516/108861 and then adding the last line from `file1` to the top of `file2` and removing it from `file1`, but is there an easier one-line solution?

Comment: `csplit` splits up to but not including the pattern.

Comment: That is the default behaviour of `csplit` with the `/pattern/` regexp form ("copy up to but not including a matching line"), so you should be able to use [this answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/202571/65304) from the question you linked, simply omitting the `+1` offset.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is very easy to modify [my solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/202573/22222) to the other question. Just remove the `next`:

```
perl -ne 'if(/XYZ/){$a=1} ; $a==1 ? print STDERR : print STDOUT;' file >f1 2>f2;
```

That will create `f1` with everything up to `XYZ` and `f2` with everything else, including the `XYZ`.

---

Alternatively, the [accepted answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/202516/22222) from the question you linked to already does pretty much what you need. It just keeps `XYZ` in the 1st file. To have it in the second, just invert the two `awk` commands:

```
awk '/XYZ/{out="file2"}{print >out}; ' out=file1 file
```

Answer (score 1):

Other variant (with `sed`)

```
sed '/XYZ/,${
             w file2
             d
            }' file >file1
```